# Deploy nuxt on AWS amplify console

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I have an aws amplify project built on top of nuxt. I'm trying to setup CI using amplify console. My build keeps failing in deploy stage, for some reason the artifacts aren't being created or can't be found:
[image]

Here's my amplify.yml file:

```
version: 0.1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

If I run `npm run generate` locally then my app is built and can be found in the **dist** folder without any problems.

did anyone manage to successfully deploy an amplify/nuxt app using the amplify console?

Thanks

**Update 1**
change the buildspec:

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run generate
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: I have the same issue, it stopped to work after 3 months, moved to S3 to deploy to production, but for some branches, I'd like to switch back to amplify console. Did you manage to get it working finally?

Comment: Haven't tested yet. see my update

Comment: I was already using `npm ci` instead of `npm i` for consistency, the problem is after many `$ ls` in the folder structure, I can't find anymore the `dist` folder. I think it's more an issue with relative/absolute path.

Comment: I will add an issue to amplify console repository.

Comment: I don't think it' an amplify issue. After a 'nom run build', a folder called '.nuxt' is created with client and server files. Those files are use further for 'npm run serve'.